# ScintillaNET in WPF XAML Issues

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, scintilla

I am trying to use `ScintillaNET` in WPF (via the `Windows Forms Host`). However I am getting an invalid XAML markup. My XAML code is:

```
<Window x:Class="ObjectiveWin.Editor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:scintilla="clr-namespace:ScintillaNET"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ObjectiveWin 2013 Express" Height="392.537" Width="628.358" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="editor_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="340" Margin="0,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="620">
        <scintilla:Scintilla></scintilla:Scintilla>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

However, Visual Studio 2012 gives me these errors:

1. `The name Scintilla does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ScintillaNET".`
2. `The tag 'Scintilla' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:ScintillaNET. Line 8  position 14.'`
3. `The name 'scintilla:Scintilla' was not found. Verify you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built`

What exactly am I doing wrong? If it matters, I am using `.NET Framework 4.5` with `VS2012`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong namespace ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms747086.aspx)).

> assembly can be omitted if the clr-namespace referenced is being
>   defined within the same assembly as the application code that is
>   referencing the custom classes.

Check this namespace:

```
xmlns:scintilla="clr-namespace:ScintillaNET;assembly=ScintillaNET"
```

Comment: Thanks. It does compile now, but `VS2012` still complains that the name `Scintilla` does not exist in `clr-namespace:ScintillaNET;assembly=ScintillaNET`. What is still going wrong?

Comment: Is this just a `VS2012` bug? It compiles but there are still XAML errors!?

Comment: It's probably bug. But if you run everything is ok.

Comment: It threw a `XAML Parser Exception` when the Window got loaded, so there is still an issue. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Ok. I fixed it now. I added SciLexer.dll as an Executable (.exe, .dll) to the project and set its build action to copy to output directory and no `XAML Parser Exception` was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue.
While searching I found a post about a seperate WPF branch referring to http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest.

If you go there and click on Branches, you can see it.

I downloaded this one and build it, then I added ScintillaNET.dll and ScintillaNET.WPF.dll to my WPF application.

But still no luck, when comparing my project with the project I got from codeplex, which worked I'v found that

My Application:  Project Properties -> Application -> Target Framework was set to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (this is not the full .NET FrameWork 4 but a light version)

The Application from codeplex was set to .NET Framework 4.  After changing my application to the full .NET Framework 4, all issues where gone.

Namespace I added to my XAML

xmlns:sn="http://scintillanet.codeplex.com"